# How to set the IP address and data of Nodes in NS3?

Tags: c++, ns-3

I have two main questions about ns-3.

1. I have my topology fully built but I want to be able to set(change) the IP addresses of nodes that exists within a NodeContainer. Is this possible and how if so?
2. I need to set the data a node is holding as I am simulating a peer to peer streaming service. I do not understand how to change the data a node holds or even see the data.

Sorry for the delay. Here is the snippet of code I use to try to set the IP address of a node. Where `csmaTopLeftParentToTopLeft` is a NodeContainer

```
node = csmaTopLeftParentToTopLeft.Get(2);

ipv4 = node->GetObject<Ipv4> (); // Get Ipv4 instance of the node

addr = ipv4->GetAddress (0, 0).GetLocal (); // Get Ipv4InterfaceAddress of xth interface.
IPAddress = Ip.c_str();
addr.Set(IPAddress);
```

This runs but if I check the value after with print statements then it shows the value was never actually changed.

Both these things do not seem like they should be this difficult to do but I have tried many ways and search the internet and could not find anything on this topic.

Comment: Show us your attempts.

Comment: Added it to the end of the question. Sorry again for the delay and thanks for the help

Comment: Ipv4 addresses are assigned when you create the interfaces on the nodes. Custom data that is to be sent from one node to another is decided by the application.

Comment: Yes but can't you only set the base? I want to set the IP of the specific nodes during runtime. So i have to create the amount of nodes needed based on data (This is when i set the base) then change the actual IP of them later.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to set an IP Address of a node.

```
 Ptr<Node> node;
 Ptr<Ipv4> ipv4;
 Ipv4InterfaceAddress addr;
 Ipv4Address addressIp;
 const char * IPAddress;

 IPAddress = Ip.c_str();

 Ptr<NetDevice> device =  devices.Get(counter);

 node = device->GetNode();

 ipv4 = node->GetObject<Ipv4>(); // Get Ipv4 instance of the node

 int32_t interface = ipv4->GetInterfaceForDevice (device);
 if (interface == -1) {
   interface = ipv4->AddInterface (device);
 }

 Ipv4InterfaceAddress ipv4Addr = Ipv4InterfaceAddress (Ipv4Address(IPAddress), Ipv4Mask ("/16"));

 ipv4->AddAddress (interface, ipv4Addr);
 ipv4->SetMetric (interface, 1);
 ipv4->SetUp (interface);
```